# Axon - Easiest way to make projection at query time

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, axon

I will usually have 5-6 events per aggregate and would like not to store projections in DB. What would be the easiest way always to make view projection at query time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to this, is that there is no easy/quick way to do this.

However, it most certainly is doable to implement a 'replay given events at request time' set up.

What I would suggest you do exists in several steps:

1. Create the query model you would like to return, which can *handle events* (use `@EventHandler` annotated methods on the model)
2. Create a Component which can handle the query that'll return the query model in step one (use a `@QueryHandler` annotated method for this.
3. The Query-Handling-Component should be able to retrieve a stream of events from the `EventStore`. If this is based on an `aggregateIdentifier`, use the `EventStore#readEvents(String)` method. If you need the entire event stream, you need to use the `StreamableMessageSource#openStream(TrackingToken)` method (note: the `EventStore` interface implements `StreamableMessageSource`)
4. Upon query handling, create a `AnnotationEventHandlerAdapter`, giving it a fresh instance of your Query Model
5. For every event in the event stream you've created in point 3, call the `AnnotationEventHandlerAdapter#handle(EventMessage)` method. This method will call the `@EventHandler` annotated methods on your Query Model object
6. If the stream is depleted, you are ensured all necessary events for your Query Model have dealt with. Thus, you can now return the Query Model

So, again, I don't think this is overly trivial, easy or quick to set up.
Additionally, step 3 has quite a caveat in there. Retrieving the stream of a given  Aggregate based on the Aggregate Identifier is pretty fast/concise, as an Aggregate in general doesn't have a lot of events.

However, retrieving the Event Stream based on a `TrackingToken`, which you'd need if your Query Model spans several Aggregates, can ensure you pull in the **entire** event store for instantiating your models on the fly. Granted, you can fine tune the point in time you want the Event Stream to return events from as you're dealing with a `TrackingToken`, but the changes are pretty high you will be incomplete and relatively slow.

However, you stated you want to retrieve events for a given Aggregate Identifier.
I'd thus think this should be a workable solution in your scenario.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for describing way to do this. Seems like something that is not supported at all in Axon. Problem with this implementation is nature of events - projections would have to hold all events (basically projection has only List<Event> eventHistory) - making it impractical to store projections (since it would be actually duplicate events).

Comment: From the definition of an Event Store, you should typically expect two ways of receiving Events from it, one being per Aggregate Identifier and two being the Event Stream at a given point in time. Hence my argument stating this would work nicely for a View per Aggregate Id, but not so much for other permutations. Not completely sure whether this is a missing feature or just being in line with the Event Store definition. Regardless, you are always welcome to file feature request for Axon: https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues